# Could not calculate the upgrade, Upgrade 12.04 to 14.04

Tags: 12.04, upgrade

I get the error

```
Could not calculate the upgrade

An unresolvable problem occurred while calculating the upgrade.

 This can be caused by:
 * Upgrading to a pre-release version of Ubuntu
 * Running the current pre-release version of Ubuntu
 * Unofficial software packages not provided by Ubuntu

If none of this applies, then please report this bug using the command 'ubuntu-bug ubuntu-release-upgrader-core' in a terminal.
```

Any solution?

Comment: Please add more information on the system you are updating

Comment: Create bootable USB drive. Select option, upgrade from 12.04 to 14.04 on the 2nd screen.